# sql Case statement bring back multiple values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to bring back the county Id and the county name. How can I fix this query?

```
DECLARE @test int = 0;


select 
CASE (@test)
    when 0 then (SELECT co.Id, co.Description
                 FROM Dictionary.Counties as co
                 INNER JOIN CountyCollaboration as cc on cc.CountyId = co.Id
                 WHERE cc.CollaborationId = (SELECT cc1.CollaborationId from CountyCollaboration as cc1
                                             WHERE cc1.CountyId = 34))
END
```

I get the error `only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

If I comment out `co.Description` so I'm only bringing back `co.Id`, I get a different error: `subquery returned more than 1 value.  This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >=, or when the subquery is used as as expression.`

Comment: If you can explain why you want to do this there may be a simple workaround which would avoid any `CASE`  or `IF` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only return one expression from a CASE statement.  Try using IF/ELSE instead.

The CASE statement in T-SQL is not a control flow statement like CASE/SWITCH in many programming languages.

Comment: In fact, there is no `CASE` statement in T-SQL. There's a `CASE` *expression*, which in common with other *expressions* computes a value.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks Phil.  As soon as it lets me I will accept your answer, I have to wait a couple more minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest restructuring your query to look like this.

```
select id, country 
from 
(select co.id
, co.country
, case @test  code for test goes here end caseresult
from all that stuff you have as a subquery in your question
) derivedtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery was returning multiple *fields* and possible multiple *records*.  A subquery like this must always return one field and one record.

I'm guessing the `INNER JOIN` is causing multiple records to be returned.  If all of the records have the same value you can to a `DISTINCT` or `TOP 1`.